# React Native how to fix something in the bottom

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I am creating a custom picker in RN and want the picker to appear from the bottom of the screen

Below is the image which shows how it is appearing currently.

Consider this as my code for the current Picker component **(child Component)**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import {View, Picker, StyleSheet, Dimensions} from 'react-native'

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    pickerDefault:{
      flex: 1,
      position: 'absolute',
      width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
      bottom: 0
    }
})

const RNPicker = (props) => {
  return (

      <Picker
        selectedValue={'js'}
        style={styles.pickerDefault}>
        <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
        <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
    </Picker>

  )
}

RNPicker.propTypes =  {

}

export default RNPicker
```

How can I make Picker stick to the bottom of the screen.?

This is how I am rendering code (won't prefer to change this code) in the **parent component**

```
<View style={{backgroundColor: backgroundViewColor, height: '100%'}}>  
<Spinner
  visible={Loading} />
  <ProgressBar {...ProgressBarProps} />
    <View style={styles.renderComponentView}>
      <Text style={[{color: defaultColor}, styles.textStyling, textStyle]}> {label}</Text>
      {CustomPicker}
       { Error.status ?  (<Text style={[styles.subText, styles.errorColor,  helperTextStyle]}>{Error.message}</Text>): null }
      <Text style={[styles.subText, errorStyle]}>{helper}</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity 
        style={[{borderColor: defaultColor, color: defaultColor}, styles.customButton]}
        onPress={getValueFromState}
        > 
        <Text style={[{borderColor: defaultColor, color: defaultColor},styles.buttonText, buttonTextStyle]}> {usedButtonText} </Text> 
      </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
</View>
```

[image]

Comment: I think this functionality not possible with react native default picker. You should use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-picker-select to get this type functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your problem and I am trying to solving it please try this :

```
<View style={{ position: "absolute", bottom: 0, flex: 1 }}>
        {< CustomPicker/>}
</View>
```

by replacing your `{customPicker}`

Comment: please send your latest code. so I will check again